# group by county sql query

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to group by County and order by county in the query below, it's not working.  How can I get it to group by and order by county?

```
    select COUNT(sr.Response) as 'Number Of Responses', 
    County = 
    (select qpa.PossibleAnswerText from CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.QuestionPossibleAnswer as qpa 
    join CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse as sr1 on qpa.Id = sr1.QuestionPossibleAnswerId
    where (sr1.QuestionId = 1 and sr.SurveyId = sr1.SurveyId)) 

    FROM CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse as sr
    where (sr.Response is not null and CAST(sr.Response as int) < 6) and (sr.QuestionId = 8)
    Group BY sr.Response, sr.SurveyId
    Order by County
```

The results below are the current results with the current query.  I want it to group by county so 4   Alameda       1 Colusa     8 Contra Costa

```
    1   Alameda
    1   Alameda
    1   Alameda
    1   Alameda
    1   Colusa
    1   Contra Costa
    1   Contra Costa
    1   Contra Costa
    1   Contra Costa
    1   Contra Costa
    1   Contra Costa
    1   Contra Costa
    1   Contra Costa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you what you need, but without sample data I can't be certain:

```
SELECT a.County, COUNT(*) 'Number of Responses'
FROM
(
SELECT
    sr.Response,
    County =
    (
        SELECT
            qpa.PossibleAnswerText
        FROM CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.QuestionPossibleAnswer AS qpa
        JOIN CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse AS sr1 ON qpa.Id = sr1.QuestionPossibleAnswerId
        WHERE (sr1.QuestionId = 1 AND sr.SurveyId = sr1.SurveyId)
    )

FROM CaresPlusParticipantSurvey.SurveyResponse AS sr
WHERE (sr.Response IS NOT NULL
AND CAST(sr.Response AS INT) < 6)
AND (sr.QuestionId = 8)
) a
GROUP BY a.County
```

Comment: very nice, that worked.  Thanks a lot, I've been trying to get this one for a while.

Comment: how could I get different ranges, like < 6, 6 to 10, 11 to 15

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sum the 'Number of Responses" and GROUP BY county:
`select sum(COUNT(sr.Response) as 'Number Of Responses')`
and
 `Group BY sr.Response, sr.SurveyId
    Order by County`

Comment: I got this error: Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.